# Adding Sphinx search daemon as a service under linux.

Tags: linux, search, sphinx

if i write

```
service start searchd
```

i get the following error unrecognized service. How can I add the searchd as a service under linux and start it?

Comment: how did you install sphinx? If from source, it doesnt create an 'init' script automatically, but they can be found online easy enough

Comment: I installed it from source. I am searching for one, but can't find it...

Comment: First result here: https://www.google.com/search?q=sphinx+search+init+ubuntu looks pretty good

Answer (score 0):

I think correct format is

```
service searchd start.
```

Check if it works?

Comment: no, it doesn't. and i checked the /etc/init.d/ folder and there isn't any searchd script